# How to tell count of non-empty strings in string array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string that is pipe delimited:

```
string line = "test|||tester||test||||||test test|"
```

I am reading this intro a string array:

```
string[] wordsArr = line.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

My goal is without manually writing a loop myself if there is a way built into the framework to see how many items in the array are not empty. Also I can't use the `RemoveEmptyEntries` property on the `StringSplitOptions` b/c where items fall within the pipes matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want to do that without a loop? Something's going to loop *somewhere* in any sane solution...

Comment: I was just curious there was anyway possible built into the framework without me having to manually do the check in a loop.

Comment: There's a big difference between not writing the loop yourself and there not being a loop at all. gunr2171's answer is what I'd have gone for - but it *does* use a loop, inside `Count`.

Comment: Correct... I edited the initial post to reflect that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
int wordCount = line.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
string[] wordsArr = line.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 7):

If all you are looking for is the count, then use `.Count` after your split.

```
string line = "test|||tester||test||||||test test|";

int notEmptyCount = line
    .Split('|')
    .Count(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

If you want to filter out the items that are empty and access all the items that remain, use `.Where` instead.

```
var notEmptyCollection = line
    .Split('|')
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Comment: Internally this will also loop over the array. But like Jon Skeet said: any sane solution will loop... :)

Comment: @Abbas, my initial thought was "no 'do' or 'for/foreach' loop". But yeah, sometimes the answer we get is not the answer we want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string line = "test|||tester||test||||||test test|";
string[] wordsArr = line.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var notEmpty = wordsArr.Count(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

find the The simplest way as below

```
string line = "test|||tester||test||||||test test|";
int notEmptyCount = line.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```

In this `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` flag parameter omits the empty values while splitting.

for further reference [check here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as what Al Belmondo self answered with.